# cordova background geolocation on terminated app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation

I am trying to work out if this is even possible.

Using Cordova I have an app requirement that will alert the user once they are in a certain location.
This needs to happen even after the app has been terminated (not in springboard).

I know you can do it when the app is running and while in background mode but is it possible once the app has been terminated?

Using the cordova-plugin-background-geolocation will handle the background work but not sure how it works when the app is no longer running.

using cordova 3.5